# Switching Model from Radio to Checkboxfor

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxfor

I'm running a MVC5 site and trying to switch it from using a radio button to a checkbox.  I've read quite a few of the other examples on this site, but can't seem to make it work.  My current ViewModel posts as NULL to the controller.  This is how it currently looks:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public string SelectedLeader { get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Personnel> Team { get;set; }
}

public class Personnel : TableEntity {
    ... other attributes here
    public bool IsLead {get;set;}
}
```

The SelectedLeader to keep track of the RowKey of the Selected element for the RadioButton, so was thinking I could switch this to IEnumerable but still doesn't look right compared to other examples.  My HTML looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
other stuff on page
    @foreach (var person in Model.Team) {
        ... print other stuff
        @Html.CheckboxFor( e => person.IsLead , new { value=@person.RowKey })
        @Html.HiddenFor(e => person.RowKey)
    }
 }

public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel viewModel) {
    ... 
}
```

When it posts back to the server, Team actually comes back as null (same with SelectedLeader but not using that ATM).  I believe something may be wrong with how I am setting the CheckboxFor but it does set its initial setting correctly.

Any ideas? And thank you.

Steve

Comment: This is very well known problem. Basically you need to use `for` instead of `foreach` in the markup, so that your helpers look like this: `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].RowKey)`. Note that here right side of lambda depends on the left side of lambda. This is how it should be in razor, other way usually indicates something wrong with the markup

Comment: Ahhh, good to know - truly appreciate that advice.  Will try the change tomorrow morning!  Hmm, can't figure how to give you reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Andrei was correct.  It doesn't seem to work with IEnumerable (even using ElementAt(i)) - I had to change my ViewModel to IList and now it works fantastic.  Truly appreciate the help.